# Cleaning up captcha image and later using Tesseract OCR (.NET)

Tags: c#, opencv, imagemagick, ocr, captcha

I'm dealing with new image captcha mechanize in my **scraping** bot,
after trying some time with ImageMagick which I more familiar with,
I ended with no luck.

those captcha images are from this kind:
[image: Text]

and specific samples are:

[image: Text]

[image: Text]

[image: Text]

after searching some solution for those specific captcha images I found this question:

[Cleaning up captcha image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44788018/cleaning-up-captcha-image)

and there a fantastic solution offered by **Simon Mourier**

unfortunately although using the same exact code offered I wasn't getting the same nice clean results:

[image: Text]

[image: Text]

[image: Text]

I left with the strong masked lines and a few dots from time to time,
I suspect it's due to the newer version of OpenCvSharp I currently have to use, since the one used at the included solution at the time is deprecated (I tried adding older version from the solution range of time but got conflicts and run-time errors with my current .net version probably). now I use the OpenCvSharp4 & OpenCvSharp4.runtime.win Nuget packages.

Any Ideas on how to get the same clean results? or what code adjustments can be done to achieve it?
The OCR part I already implemented and it working well.

Thanks!

Comment: I suggest that this activity is unethical. Attempting to subvert the CAPTCHA protection shows a lack of respect for the owner of the server, whether they are doing it to protect their bandwidth or their business