# how to calculate the area between two cars

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I would like to know if from an image like the example it is possible to calculate the area between two consecutive cars:

Detect the two objects, calculate the distances between my camera and the two objects so deduce the area between the two objects

Any advice or references would be welcome thanks

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/4IM6y.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Osg7D.jpg)

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36254452/counting-cars-opencv-python-issue/36274515#36274515

Comment: How accurate do you want the measurement to be?

Comment: Precise enough. The goal is an app  with the help of a camera,  that  will tell the driver if the space is enough to park his car

Answer (score 0):

This is not a super scalable solution as it would vary by country.  But license plates (at least in the US) are always of a similar dimension.  This could be used to give you almost perfect distance reference and they are easy to detect.  The difficulty remaining would be in estimating the space taken up by the partial view of the near car... but this would significantly reduce the complexity of the problem.  To get that remaining bit, I would likely try to identify a tire/ hubcap and apply an offset to that... as I imagine that will get you pretty close (within 1-2 feet)

Comment: thanks.. I had thought about it but I don’t have the license plates on both sides