# A good way to identify cars at night in a video

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection, contour, feature-extraction

I'm trying to identify car contours at night in a video (**[Video Link](https://youtu.be/dqf4xLZGXT8)** is the link and you can download it from **[HERE](https://qdownloader.net/youtube-video-downloader)**). I know that `object detection` based on R-CNN or YOLO can do this job. However, I want something more simple and more faster beacause **all I want is to identify moving cars in real-time**. (And I don't have a decent GPU.) I can do it **pretty well in the day time** using the background subtruction method to find the contours of cars:
[image]

Because the light condition in the day time is rather stable, the big contours in the foremask are almost all cars. By setting a threshold of the contours' size, I can easily get the cars' contours.
However, things are much different and complicated at night mainly because of **the lights of cars**. See pictures below:

[image]

[image]

The lights on the ground also have high contrast to the background so they are also contours in the foreground mask. In order to drop those lights, I'm trying to **find the differences between light contours and car contours**. By far, I've extracted the contour's **area, centroid, perimeter, convexity, hight and width of bounding rectangle** as features for evaluation. Here is the code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import random
random.seed(100)
# ===============================================
# get video
video = "night_save.avi"
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video)
# fg bg subtract model (MOG2)
fgbg = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2(history=500, detectShadows=True) # filter model detec gery shadows for removing
# for writing video:
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('night_output.avi',fourcc,20.0,(704,576))
#==============================================
frameID = 0
contours_info = []
# main loop:
while True:
#============================================
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret:
    #====================== get and filter foreground mask ================
        original_frame = frame.copy()
        fgmask = fgbg.apply(frame)
        #==================================================================
        # filter kernel for denoising:
        kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (2, 2))
        # Fill any small holes
        closing = cv2.morphologyEx(fgmask, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
        # Remove noise
        opening = cv2.morphologyEx(closing, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
        # Dilate to merge adjacent blobs
        dilation = cv2.dilate(opening, kernel, iterations = 2)
        # threshold (remove grey shadows)
        dilation[dilation < 240] = 0
    #=========================== contours ======================
        im, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(dilation, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        # extract every contour and its information:
        for cID, contour in enumerate(contours):
            M = cv2.moments(contour)
            # neglect small contours:
            if M['m00'] < 400:
                continue
            # centroid
            c_centroid = int(M['m10']/M['m00']), int(M['m01']/M['m00'])
            # area
            c_area = M['m00']
            # perimeter
            try:
                c_perimeter = cv2.arcLength(contour, True)
            except:
                c_perimeter = cv2.arcLength(contour, False)
            # convexity
            c_convexity = cv2.isContourConvex(contour)
            # boundingRect
            (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
            # br centroid
            br_centroid = (x + int(w/2), y + int(h/2)) 
            # draw rect for each contour: 
            cv2.rectangle(original_frame,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)
            # draw id:
            cv2.putText(original_frame, str(cID), (x+w,y+h), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 3, (127, 255, 255), 1)
            # save contour info
            contours_info.append([cID,frameID,c_centroid,br_centroid,c_area,c_perimeter,c_convexity,w,h])
    #======================= show processed frame img ============================
        cv2.imshow('fg',dilation)
        cv2.imshow('origin',original_frame)
        # save frame image:
        cv2.imwrite('pics/{}.png'.format(str(frameID)), original_frame)
        cv2.imwrite('pics/fb-{}.png'.format(str(frameID)), dilation)
        frameID += 1
        k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
        if k == 27:
            cap.release()
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break
    else:
        break
#==========================save contour_info=========================
import pandas as pd
pd = pd.DataFrame(contours_info,  columns = ['ID','frame','c_centroid','br_centroid','area','perimeter','convexity','width','height'])
pd.to_csv('contours.csv')
```

However, I don't see much difference in the features I extracted between lights and cars. Some large lights on the ground can be differed with **area** and **preimeter** but it's still hard to differ small lights. Could somebody give me some instructions on this? Maybe some more valuable features or another different method?

### Edit:

Thank for @ZdaR's advice. It makes me consider of using `cv2.cvtColor` to switch the frame image into **another colorspace**. The reason for doing that is to make the color difference between **headlight itself** and **light on the ground** more obvious so we can detect headlights more precisely. See the differece after switching colourspace:

**ORIGIN(the colour of light on the ground is similar to car light itself):**

[image]

**AFTER SWITCHING(one becomes blue and the other becomes red):**

[image]

So what I'm doing now is

**1.Switch the colorspace**;

**2.Filter the swithced frame with certain colour filter (filter out blues, yellows and keep the red in order to keep the car headlights only.)**

3.Feed the flitered frame to background subtruction model and get the foreground mask then dilation.

Here is the code for doing that:

```
ret, frame = cap.read()
if ret:
#====================== switch and filter ================
col_switch = cv2.cvtColor(frame, 70)
lower = np.array([0,0,0])
upper = np.array([40,10,255])   
mask = cv2.inRange(col_switch, lower, upper)
res = cv2.bitwise_and(col_switch,col_switch, mask= mask)
#======================== get foreground mask=====================
fgmask = fgbg.apply(res)
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (2, 2))
# Dilate to merge adjacent blobs
d_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (3, 3))
dilation = cv2.dilate(fgmask, d_kernel, iterations = 2)
dilation[dilation < 255] = 0
```

And I can get this foreground mask with headlights (and some noise too):

[image]

Based on this step, I can detect the cars' headlights pretty accurately and drop out the light on the ground:

[image]

However, I still don't know how to identify the car based on these headlights.

Comment: A very simple approach to detect cars in the night time would be to detect their headlights, as they seem to be a very prominent feature, You can apply various filters such as size of contour, distance between two contours to confirm the given contours are of head light itself.

Comment: Hi @ZdaR. The headlight is merged with car itself. You can check the second and third image in the post. The headlight is not seperated.

Comment: Have you read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36274515/2286337)?

Comment: @zindarod Yes and I've reproduced that method to counting cars in daytime. But it can't deal with the difficulties at night.

Comment: Post a few unedited images where you're getting false positives.

Comment: @zindarod. One is added in the post. Are you able to access to the video whose link is provided in the post?

Comment: Is a thermal camera a possibility maybe?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Emm..nope..the camera is fixed..