# error: (-215:Assertion failed) npoints >= 0 in function 'cv::convexityDefects'

Tags: python, opencv

```
 defects = cv2.convexityDefects(cnt, hull)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.8.1) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\convhull.cpp:319: error: (-215:Assertion failed) npoints >= 0 in function 'cv::convexityDefects'
```

i tried resolving the issue by ensuring that the contours and hull variables have valid values and that their lengths are greater than or equal to 3 before passing them to the cv2.convexityDefects function.

```
if cnt is not None and hull is not None and len(cnt) >= 3 and len(hull) >= 3:
    defects = cv2.convexityDefects(cnt, hull)
else:
    print("Invalid contour or not enough points in the contour or hull.")
    defects = None

# finding convexity defects
defects = cv2.convexityDefects(cnt, hull)
count_defects = 0
cv2.drawContours(thresh1, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)  # to draw all contours pass -1
```

Comment: There is a second call of `cv2.convexityDefects` in that example of yours that is not protected by that check. Is that where the exception is coming from? A proper [mcve] wouldn't hurt.... as well as a complete backtrace including the line number.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked the source code of [`cv::convexityDefects`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/4.x/modules/imgproc/src/convhull.cpp#L313) the error probably comes form `npoints = points.checkVector(2, CV_32S);`

You must pass the variable as signed 32-bit integer (np.int32) and the correct shape of (N, 2).

Comment: This answer is just a wild guess due to the lack of proper [mcve], and quite likely incorrect. I'm willing to bet that `cnt` is the output of `findContours`, and `hull` comes from `convexHull`, so both have the right datatype. The only evidence of a potential cause of error based on that incomplete snippet of code OP provided is described in the comment I left below the question. I think it's likely that that contour being processed came from a single pixel, so it really doesn't have enough points. But until OP gives us all the necessary info, it's all just speculation.

Comment: I assumed the points were enough, but when I have to assume something indicates a lack of enough explanation/reproducible example. You're totally right.

Comment: @DanMašek BTW:) I was looking at your profile and just before seeing and testing he notification I was seeing your answer to a question. nice work:)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36254452/counting-cars-opencv-python-issue/36274515#36274515

Comment: Thanks :) Yeah, that one was fun to play with.

Comment: Oh and now that I think about it -- well done on actually reading the source code. I rarely see people actually doing that, and OpenCV is quite a doozy at times. :)

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I'm getting habituated to it. and I agree some parts of OpenCV are a mess:)